# How to get session in IE Driver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jsessionid

I need to track the session id for some special requirement of the application and have to match the same in Access Log page in the application UI. I tried with the following code and it is working properly in firefox driver.

```
String ASPNET_SessionId = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID").toString();

strSessionID = ASPNET_SessionId.split("=")[1].split(";")[0];
```

We have a feature in out framework that we can execute in any browser either Firefox or IE. But when trying to execute my test in IE, its getting null pointer exception while getting the session id. Basically the session is coming as null.

I tried invoking the IE as follows:

```
strIEDriverPath = currentDir+(FileHandlerClass.readPropertiesXml(strPropertiesFilePath, "IEDriverPath"));

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", strIEDriverPath);

DesiredCapabilities capab = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

capab.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capab);
```

But still no help....

Can any one suggest me how to get the session id from IE driver? Any help or suggestion whould be highly appreciated..

Comment: What happens if, instead of explicitly introducing flakiness into your IE configuration (which you've done by using the `INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS` capability), you [correctly configure Protected Mode](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) for use with WebDriver?

Comment: configured the IE Protected mode properly and removed the capability. But still getting null pointer exception. Not able to analyze why its happening. Any suggestion please...

Answer (score 0):

I also tested your code likes this;

```
File file = new File("C:\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Do something test.
System.out.println(driver.manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID").toString());
```

My output is

```
JSESSIONID=JPlxPwhMkyYdpmQvJt73mSjd5p9fnn1VHfq1yvbdvZ9gnG1380rf!-1092181086; path=/
```

My OS is Windows7 64 bit and IEDriverServer.exe is also 64 bit version.So I guess your `driver.manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID").toString()` has no problem.So check your **file path** and check your **IEDriverServer.exe** version.

Comment: I also have the same configuration as Windows 7 and 64bit. Double checked the file path and the IEDriver version, Path is correct and IEDriver is 2.44 latest one. Still m getting null pointer exception while executing the line "driver.manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID").toString()"

Answer (score -1):

```
SessionId sessionId = null;
sessionId = ((InternetExplorerDriver) wDriver).getSessionId();
```